# Grep to get output after the first instance of a string

Tags: awk, grep

I'm currently using a CentOS image from Docker. What I want to do is get a certain value after grep encounters a certain string. In this case the string is 'inet'.

What I have done so far:

```bsh
# ifconfig | grep 'inet'
```

Gives me the following output:

```
inet 192.168.208.4  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.223.255
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
```

However, I only need the first inet ip address (192.168.208.4) to later store in an environment variable. I'm open to using alternatives to grep such as awk. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest with CentOS/RHEL: `hostname -I`

Comment: @Cyrus it works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a command that outputs more than one line of text, and you want only thue first line of output.  The `head` command may be useful here:

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet' | head -n 1
```

If it's only the IP address that you want, then you could use `awk`:

```
ifconfig | awk '/inet/ { print $2; exit }'
```

This would extract the second whitespace-separated field from the first line that contains the string `inet`, and then terminate.

Comment: It's only the IP address that I want. When I ran your awk command nothing displayed in the output tho.

Comment: @SimonGarfe Did you delete spaces at the start of the line in the output of `ifconfig` in the question?  Try with `/inet/` instead of `/^inet/`.

Comment: that worked thank you.

Comment: With GNU grep `-m1` is the same as piping to `head` except more efficient. But concur awk is the better solution here..